# Beginner's Java Code Help: Newton Raphson Square Root Loop

Tags: java

In my Java class for college we are learning about the Looping control structure, and we got an assignment to code a little program that I am guessing is supposed to give the square root of a number and keep on taking the square root until the difference or accuracy is met. Here are the instructions:

"Write a class called NewtonRaphson that can be used to find an approximate solution of sqrt(a) using Newton's method, for any positive real number.

Note: sqrt(a) can be expressed in functional notation as follows: f(x) = x2 – a, 
From which f ' (x) = 2 * x,

Print the iteration sequence and the approximation for each iteration. (That is, in a tabular form).

Write a driver class called TestNewton. Use the following data to test the class NewtonRaphson.

•   The initial guess is 5.0 
•   In this exercise, the process terminates when the difference between two consecutive approximations is less than 0.00005"

I have my code linked at the bottom here, the main class and the test class, but I am not getting the looping result I am just getting the same square root of 5 when I type in 5 after running the program. Can someone please tell me where I messed up on?

Thanks, I am really new to coding, and this took forever to make and I had to ask for some friends help.

Main Class: http://pastebin.com/eiUJFJjQ 
Test Class: http://pastebin.com/sJ4dB5uZ

Or if you prefer the code here it is:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat; 
import java.text.DecimalFormat; 

public class NewtonRaphson { 

static final double DIFFERENCE = 0.00005; 
double n; 
double x; 
double derivative; 
double function; 
double xold; 
double xnew; 
int i; 

public NewtonRaphson(double n2, int x2) 

{ 
    n=n2; 
    x=x2; 
    function = Math.pow(n, 2)-x; 
    derivative = 2*n; 
    xnew=n-function/derivative; 
    xold=0; 
} 

boolean positive() 

{ 
    return (n >= 0); 
} 

public double findXNew(double xold2) 

{ 
    function = Math.pow(xold2, 2)-x; 
    derivative = 2*xold2; 
    return xold2-function/derivative; 
} 

public void findSqRtA() 

{ 

    i=0; 
    while(Math.abs(xnew-xold)> DIFFERENCE)

{ 

    xold=xnew; 
    xnew=findXNew(xold); 
    i++; 
    System.out.println(this); 

} 

    System.out.println("\nIteration completed, difference is less than 0.00005"); 

} 

public String toString() 

{ 
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(); DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf; 
    df.applyPattern("0.00000000"); 

    return "The approximate value of the square root of "+x+" is " + xnew + "\n" + 

    "The number of iterations is " + i; 
} 
}
```

and

```
import java.io.Console; 
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class TestNewton { 

public static void main(String[] args) { 

Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("Enter a number you would like to find the square root of"); 

int a = reader.nextInt(); 

NewtonRaphson nr = new NewtonRaphson(5.0, a); 

nr.findSqRtA(); 

} 
}
```

My output is this, but I want it to take the square root after each iteration's result.

```
Enter a number you would like to find the square root of
5
The approximate value of the square root of 5.0 is 2.3333333333333335
The number of iterations is 1
The approximate value of the square root of 5.0 is 2.238095238095238
The number of iterations is 2
The approximate value of the square root of 5.0 is 2.2360688956433634
The number of iterations is 3
The approximate value of the square root of 5.0 is 2.236067977499978
The number of iterations is 4

Iteration completed, difference is less than 0.00005
```

Comment: well, it's time for you to find out what debug is

Comment: That's way too much code. Please trim it down to what is necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yeah that's way too long, friend. Try to shorten it a bit.

Comment: It works for me.  That is, it's producing the correct result.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I thought the program is supposed to take the square root of each new answer from the previous square root, it constantly takes the square root of 5.

Comment: That doesn't look like what the assignment is.  But if that's what you want to do, then just get `findSqRtA` to **return** its result, then put the code that creates `new NewtonRaphson` and calls `findSqRtA` in a loop that keeps using the previous square-root until the answers are as close as you want.  (The final answer should always be 1.)

Answer (score 1):

**Newton-Raphson** method is very interesting. You can use it to approximate real-valued function roots. **x<sup>2</sup>** is only one of them. Check this [fractals](http://cahit.wordpress.com/2009/03/06/fractals-with-newton-raphson-method/) produced with Newton-Raphson method. So, do not underestimate Newton-Raphson.

Your code works. But your expectations are mistaken, you think that on every iteration you will update the guess. The code actually does it in the while loop.

You may do something like this, the epsilon may also be a parameter.
First, you give a large epsilon find a square root estimation.
Then input the last approximation with a slightly smaller epsilon, until you are satisfied with the result.
I think this is what you expect.

You can simplify the code. Check this [code](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/13flow/Sqrt.java.html) out.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually producing the correct result for me. Therefore I'm not sure what the problem is.
For help with Newton's method you can refer to this article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method

Can you show us your output?

"I thought the program is supposed to take the square root of each new answer from the previous square root, it constantly takes the square root of 5. But I want it to take the square root of each iteration's result"

Oh, I see, that's because you have this:

```
NewtonRaphson nr = new NewtonRaphson(5.0, a);
```

Simply replace the 5.0 above with your previous number.

Comment: I thought the program is supposed to take the square root of each new answer from the previous square root, it constantly takes the square root of 5.

Comment: Or at least that's what I am trying to do. My output is this:
Enter a number you would like to find the square root of
5
The approximate value of the square root of 5.0 is 2.3333333333333335
The number of iterations is 1
The approximate value of the square root of 5.0 is 2.238095238095238
The number of iterations is 2
The approximate value of the square root of 5.0 is 2.2360688956433634
The number of iterations is 3
The approximate value of the square root of 5.0 is 2.236067977499978
The number of iterations is 4

Iteration completed, difference is less than 0.00005

Comment: But I want it to take the square root of each iteration's result.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you. Sorry for the... silly question, Im new at this.